# How can I do this Uniform, Binominal, and Poisson distribution BY unidrnd, binornd, and poissrnd?

Tags: probability, statistics

The information is like that :
Generate 1000 random variates in R language for the following discrete models of risk and test that the sample generated truly represents the intended distribution using the X^2 goodness of fit test. The α is 0.05.

How can I do this Uniform, Binominal, and Poisson distribution BY unidrnd, binornd, and poissrnd?

Comment: I am not familiar with the R functions you mention. In R, you can generate 1000 realizations of $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = .4)$ using the R statement `rbinom(1000, 10, .4).` Similarly, `runif(1000, 2, 5)` for $\mathsf{Unif}(2, 5)$ and `rpois(1000, 5)` for $\mathsf{Pois}(5).$ // When you do the chi-sq GOF test make sure the categories you choose all have expected counts greater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline for how you could do this for $Y \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$

**Step 1.** Generate 1000 realizations of $Y.$

**Step 2.** Choose ten intervals $(0, .1],\,(.1,,2], \dots, (.9,1]$ as the $n = k$
categories for the GOF test, and determine the observed number $f_i$ in each
category.

**Step 3.** The expected counts in each category will be $E_i = 100.$ Compute
the chi-squared GOF statistic $Q,$ and reject fit to this uniform distribution
at the 5% level of significance, if $Q > c,$ where the $c = 16.92$ cuts 5% 
of the probability from the upper tail of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 9).$ The
degrees of freedom are $\nu = k - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9.$

```
 qchisq(.95, 9)
 ## 16.91898
```

The formula for $Q$ is
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(f_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}.$$

---

Here is R code showing one possible way to implement these steps.

In general, the difficult part to automate is to find the frequency for each
category. (For one run, you could just print out 
the randomly generated values of `y` in sorted order `sort(y)` and
do the counts by hand. For *discrete* data, you could use `table(y)`.) In this case, I used a non-plotted histogram
to do the counting.

Results from one run are shown at lines marked
`##`. Of course, this is a random process, and each run will give somewhat different results.

```
 m = 1000;  a = 0;  b = 1;  k = 10; E = m/k;  cutp = seq(a, b, len=k+1)
 y = runif(m, a, b)
 hist(y, br=cutp, ylim=c(0,110), col="skyblue2", label=T)  # See plot
 f = hist(y, br=cutp, plot=F)$counts;  f    # use `hist` to get obs freq
 ##  87 107 108  94 110 101 100 102  91 100
 q = sum((f - E)^2/E);  q                   # GOF statistic
 ## 5.04
 c = qchisq(.95, k-1);  c                   # critical value
 ## 16.91898
 p.val = 1 - pchisq(q, k-1);  p.val         # P-value
 ## 0.8308075
```

For this run (as for about 95% of all runs) we do not reject the null
hypothesis that the generated observations are from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1):$

First, because $Q = 5.04 < c = 16.92.$

Second, because the P-value 0.83 exceeds
0.05 = 5%.

[image]